# ¿Cómo hacer una caja de confirmar de SI o NO en Asp,net/C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Tengo un formulario y con este un botón de envío.Lo que quiero hacer es que cuando se presione dicho botón, me salga una ventanita con dos opciones: Aceptar y Cancelar.

Me gustaría algo mas como:

Si presiono "Aceptar"
   entonces ejecútame el código de insertar datos
si presiono "Cancelar"
  Entonces cierra el actual caja de dialogo.

El siguiente código(que es lo que tengo actualmente)funciona, pero con el típico alert de javascript.

Este es mi botón:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnenviarreserva" runat="server"  Text="Reservar" OnClick="btnenviarreserva_Click" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to submit ?')" />
```

Y este es mi CodeBehind,el cual inserta los datos del formulario hacia la base de datos:

```
 protected void btnenviarreserva_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Codigo para hacer insercion de datos en la BD


        SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source = MEGATRON; Initial Catalog = RentCar; Integrated Security = True");
        SqlCommand insert = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Reservas(CedulaC, NombreC, ApellidosC,TelefonoC, CodigoAuto, TipoAutoR, MarcaAutoR, ModeloAutoR, Cantdias, Totalpagar) values(@Cedula, @NombreC, @ApellidosC, @TelefonoC,@Placa,@Tipo, @Marca, @Modelo,@Cantdias, @Total)", cnn);

        insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cedula", cedula.Text);
        insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NombreC", nombre.Text);
        insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ApellidosC", apellidos.Text);
        insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TelefonoC", tel.Text);
        insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Placa", placa.Text);
        insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Tipo", tipoauto.Text);
        insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Marca", marca.Text);
        insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Modelo", Modelo.Text);
        insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cantdias", Cantidaddias2.Text);
        insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Total", Totalapagar2 .Text);


        try
        {
            cnn.Open();
            insert.ExecuteNonQuery();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            cnn.Close();
        }




    }
```

Answer (score 0):

para esto utiliza jquery y jqueryui mira aqui un ejemplo

aqui el web form:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="jqueryui_and_aspnet.WebForm1" %>


<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#confirm-dialog").dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                modal: true,
                buttons: {
                    "OK": function (e) {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                        <%=Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(mainOK, "") %>
                    },
                    "Cancel": function () {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            });

            $('#<%=mainOK.ClientID%>').click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $("#confirm-dialog").dialog("open");
            });
        });

        function plain_confirm() {
            return confirm('Are you sure?');
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body style="font-weight: 700">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
     <div id="form2">
        <%--<asp:Button runat="server" ID="mainOK" Text="OK" OnClick="" />--%>
         <asp:Button ID="mainOK" runat="server" Text="OK"  OnClick="mainOK_OnClick"/>
    </div>

    <div id="confirm-dialog">
        Are you sure?
    </div>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Aqui el metodo que manda a llamar.

```
protected void mainOK_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Write("realiza accion");
        }
```